# Estructura if-else no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!usr/bin/env python
def vocales(string):
    if "A" or "a" or "E" or "e" or "I" or "i" or "O" or "o" or "U" or "u" in string:
        nvocalesami = (string.count("a"))
        nvocalesama = (string.count("A"))
        nvocalesemi = (string.count("e"))
        nvocalesema = (string.count("E"))
        nvocalesimi = (string.count("i"))
        nvocalesima = (string.count("I"))
        nvocalesomi = (string.count("o"))
        nvocalesoma = (string.count("O"))
        nvocalesumi = (string.count("u"))
        nvocalesuma = (string.count("U"))
        part1 = (nvocalesami + nvocalesama + nvocalesemi + nvocalesema + nvocalesimi + nvocalesima)
        part2 = (nvocalesomi + nvocalesoma + nvocalesumi + nvocalesuma)
        todo = (part1 + part2)
        return ("Hay",todo,"vocales en la frase")
    else:
        return("No hay vocales en la frase")
```

Tengo un problema con este codigo al utilizar la funcion vocales con un argumento sin vocales por ejemplo:

Salida

```
vocales("r")
Hay 0 vocales en la frase
```

---

Porque no sale "No hay vocales en la frase"?

Comment: Ya te han dado la solución por lo que no voy a responder , solo decir que puedes sustituir todo eso por `if any(x in "AaEeIiOoUu" for x in string):` :)

Comment: Según el tamaño de `string`, será más eficiente invertir la comprobación: `if any(x in string for x in "AaEeIiOoUu")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!usr/bin/env python
def vocales(string):
 if "A" in string or "a" in string or "E" in string or "e" in string or "I" in string or "i" in string or "O" in string or "o" in string or "U" in string or "u" in string :
    nvocalesami = (string.count("a"))
    nvocalesama = (string.count("A"))
    nvocalesemi = (string.count("e"))
    nvocalesema = (string.count("E"))
    nvocalesimi = (string.count("i"))
    nvocalesima = (string.count("I"))
    nvocalesomi = (string.count("o"))
    nvocalesoma = (string.count("O"))
    nvocalesumi = (string.count("u"))
    nvocalesuma = (string.count("U"))
    part1 = (nvocalesami + nvocalesama + nvocalesemi + nvocalesema + nvocalesimi + nvocalesima)
    part2 = (nvocalesomi + nvocalesoma + nvocalesumi + nvocalesuma)
    todo = (part1 + part2)
    return ("Hay " + str(todo) + " vocales en la frase")
 else:
    return("No hay vocales en la frase")

print vocales("r")
```

Este código funciona, el problema residía en que no agrupaste la expresión del if con paréntesis.

Comment: Pero que tiene que ver poner los parentesis? Segun tengo entendido sirven para el orden de las operaciones. En el if la expresion lleva parentesis obligatoriamente? (Ademas aunque pusiera los parentesis siempre me va a salir "No hay vocales en la frase" independientemente de que la frase tenga vocales)

Comment: no son obligatorios, pero cuando evaluas varias condiciones lógicas seguidas es mejor agruparlas para no generar confusiones como esta.

Comment: lo quise hacer tan rapido que no me habia fijado en que detecta. acabo de editar mi respuesta y ahora si que funciona aunque no queda una solucion tan limpia

Answer (score 0):

utiliza el siguiente codigo

```
def vocales(string):
    if any(x not in string for x in ('A', 'E',   'I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u')):
    nvocalesami = (string.count("a"))
    nvocalesama = (string.count("A"))
    nvocalesemi = (string.count("e"))
    nvocalesema = (string.count("E"))
    nvocalesimi = (string.count("i"))
    nvocalesima = (string.count("I"))
    nvocalesomi = (string.count("o"))
    nvocalesoma = (string.count("O"))
    nvocalesumi = (string.count("u"))
    nvocalesuma = (string.count("U"))
    part1 = (nvocalesami + nvocalesama + nvocalesemi + nvocalesema + nvocalesimi + nvocalesima)
    part2 = (nvocalesomi + nvocalesoma + nvocalesumi + nvocalesuma)
    todo = (part1 + part2)
    return ("Hay",todo,"vocales en la frases")
else:
    return("No hay vocales en la frase")
```

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que el `if` está evaluando cada `or` como **varias** condiciones lógicas individuales y no como una condición única compuesta, es decir, está evaluando cada operando, y al encontrar el primer operando como cierto entrá en la condición.

Esto lo puedes probar dejando solo la siguiente condición:

```
if "A":
```

Y va a ejecutarse de la misma forma en que se está ejecutando tu código actualmente.

El problema lo solucionas fácilmente encerrando las condiciones en paréntesis, de la siguiente manera:

```
if ("A" or "a" or "E" or "e" or "I" or "i" or "O" or "o" or "U" or "u") in string:
```

Y ahí vas a obtener la salida:

```
$ python vocales.py
No hay vocales en la frase
```